# How to specify the value column for CSV output of data model with ForeignKey in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I would like to export CSV file of a Django Model that is using ForeignKey.
By default, the file is exported with ID value of ForeignKey model, but I want have other column's data as value of the CSV file.

Here is an example:

models.py:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    assign = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py:

```
def export_to_csv(request):
    task = task_set.all()
    task_list = task.values()
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(task_list.values()))
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=task.csv'
    df.to_csv(path_or_buf=response)

    return response
```

If I implement as above, column for Member model would be ID. But I want to have name column of Member model on CSV file.

Comment: You want to annotate the member name in queryset; something like, Task.objects.annotate(name=F('assign__name')).